# Json Object to object

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following JSON object and I would like to convert it to a Javascript Object.

```
let data = [{"agreg": "Count", "colunm": "var_pj", "label": "Type 1"}, 
            {"agreg": "First", "colunm": "qtd_if", "label": "Type 2"}, 
            {"agreg": "Sum", "colunm": "qtd_ag_if","label": "Type 3"}];
```

I would like to put some key/values into a Javascript object like this:

```
let disVars = {'var_pj'  : 'Count([',
              'qtd_if'   : 'First([',
              'qtd_ag_if': 'Sum([' };
```

I have tried using the following code:

```
let disVars = data.map(function(item){
    let col = item.colunm.toString();
    let agr = item.agreg.toString();
    return col + ': ' + agr + '([';
    });
```

But the result for console.log(disVars) is:

```
 "var_pj: Count([",
 "qtd_if : First([",
 "qtd_ag_if: Sum(["
```

Comment: Did you google first? `JSON.parse`

Comment: it is because you mixed string with object. Object is javascript and you return/create only string

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Thank you, guys. The solution bellow did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's working solution for your problem. I used [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) function to convert key-value array into JS object.

```js
let data = [{"agreg": "Count", "colunm": "var_pj", "label": "Type 1"}, 
            {"agreg": "First", "colunm": "qtd_if", "label": "Type 2"}, 
            {"agreg": "Sum", "colunm": "qtd_ag_if","label": "Type 3"}];

let result = Object.fromEntries(data.map(item => [
  item.colunm, item.agreg + '(['
]));

console.log(result);
```

If you need maximum browser capability you can also use the code bellow. The code doesn't uses `Object.fromEntries` API. Instead I created an empty object and looped over data then put new properties to the object.

```js
let data = [{"agreg": "Count", "colunm": "var_pj", "label": "Type 1"}, 
            {"agreg": "First", "colunm": "qtd_if", "label": "Type 2"}, 
            {"agreg": "Sum", "colunm": "qtd_ag_if","label": "Type 3"}];

let result = new Object();
for (var item of data) {
  result[item.colunm] = item.agreg + '([';
}

console.log(result);
```